# Python PULP sorting results

Tags: python, sorting, pulp

I am using PULP for linear optimization reasons. Everything works fine and I am getting results and I am printing each of them:

```
for i in range (0, len(opt_P)):
    print (opt_P[i].name + " = " + str(opt_P[i].varValue))
```

output looks like this:

```
0 = 20.0
1 = 20.0
10 = 1200.0
11 = 1200.0
2 = 20.0
3 = 20.0
4 = 20.0
5 = 20.0
6 = 1200.0
7 = 1200.0
8 = 45.895992
9 = 1200.0
```

I want to sort the results with `opt_P.sort()` function, but I am getting error:

> '<' not supported between instances of 'LpVariable' and 'LpVariable'

Also I tried this `opt_P.sort(key=lambda s: s[1])` and this one also: `opt_P.sort(key=lambda s: s["name"])` but getting error:

> 'LpVariable' object is not subscriptable

Could you please support me in solving this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the key function to be used.

Example:

```
>>> vars_list
[x_2, x_3, x_0, x_1, x_9, x_8, x_6, x_4, x_7, x_5]
>>> vars_list.sort(key=lambda x:x.name)
>>> vars_list
[x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6, x_7, x_8, x_9]
```

or if you want to sort them as integers

```
>>> vars_list.sort(key=lambda x:int(x.name))
```

Comment: Id did not work :( I got absolutely the same results: 
`print (opt_P)
opt_P.sort(key=lambda s:s.name)
print (opt_P)`
output:
`[0, 1, 10, 11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 10, 11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Comment: In that case you need lambda x: int(x.name)

Comment: Thank you very much. x: int(x.name)  worked perfectly